# Is "hotel lot" = "hotel parking lot"?

Tags: word-meaning

Can I use just "lot" to refer to a "parking lot", when it is accompanied by the place where the parking lot is? Example:

- I park in the hotel parking lot. (correct)
- I park in the hotel lot. (?)

It seems to me that the last sentence refers to a generic unconstructed terrain.

Comment: It would be hard to understand your second sentence in any other sense. Seems adequate to me.

Comment: You can definitely omit 'parking' if it has been used already or the context is clearly stated, e.g. I didn't know whether to park in the hotel lot or the lot at the mall.

Comment: For me it sounds funny _not_ to omit it since "park" is repeated. I think your second version is what any native speaker would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of how context is key.

Yes, the phrase *the hotel lot* could be used to refer to what you call "generic unconstructed terrain." After all, a lot is:

> **[lot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lot)** (*noun*) a portion of land; a measured parcel of land having fixed boundaries and designated on a plot or survey : *built his home on a half-acre lot*.

If you and I were in the construction business, and we were both aware that new hotel was being built on an empty lot on the west side of town, we might have this dialogue:

> **You**: Dispatch wants to know where to send this cement truck.
>   **Me**: They need to send it to the hotel lot.

In this case, we don't mean a parking lot, we mean the plot of land where the new hotel will be built.

However, your sentence wasn't anything like that. You said:

> I park in the hotel lot.

Most of the time, people regularly park in parking lots, so most native speakers hearing that would assume that you park your vehicle in the hotel's parking lot.

Here's an example of this language being used in this way, found on a [hiker's website](https://patch.com/connecticut/brookfield/henry-preserve-newtown):

> You can **park in the church lot**, near the utility shed in the back, since the trail begins directly behind the propane tank storage area.

Here's another example from a traveler's discussion [website](https://www.disboards.com/threads/legoland-hotel-check-in-before-going-to-park.3513045/):

> You could **park in the hotel lot**, rather than the general lot. The hotel is basically right at the park entrance, so the hotel parking is very convenient.

Another [blogger](http://lifefromtheroots.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-find-tombstone-in-old-cemetery.html) says:

> **Park in the cemetery lot** behind the First Parish-Unitarian Church [or] **park in the St. Brigid Church lot**.

So, yes, *lot* is very commonly used for *parking lot*, particularly when you are talking about parking and therefore the context makes it obvious what kind of "lot" you are referring to.